# Scala: adding element to ArrayBuffer on index

Tags: scala, arraybuffer

I just started learning Scala, trying to code a simple game to learn it's syntax and some basic rules. I'd be grateful if anyone could help me with a simple problem. I created simple board filled with ".". Now I want to change one "." on the certain index and put there "X". In java it would look like this:

```
board[col][row] = symbol;
```

This is the board part:

```
val board = {
 collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
 collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.fill(cols, rows)(".")
}

def show(): Unit = {
 board.foreach(x => println(x.mkString))
}

def setField(col:Int, row:Int, fieldSymbol:String): Unit = {
 //fieldSymbol on index, which is (col*row) as it's 1d array
 //thought board.apply(col*row): fieldSymbol might work but it's not 
 //correct I guess
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: Use `board(i)` to access the i-th value of a collection (same as Java's `[i]`).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it's that simple.

Comment: `collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()` This is creating an empty array then (since you don't do anything with it), discarding it. You only need the `fill` line

Comment: Let me ask some more questions so I won't be creating many trash topics. When I have `(cols, rows)` then it means I have something like 2d array? Like, can I do `board(col, row) = fieldSymbol` ?

Comment: You have a two-d array, but it's represented as an array of arrays. It's just Java (in fact a Scala `Array` _is_ a Java `Array`). So you need `board(col)(row)` (I'm working so I'm not going to be a real-time further-question-answering service, post "proper" questions if required (or consult a Scala tutorial!)

Comment: I was looking through docs to find some magical stuff and it's that simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement setField for a flat array like this

```
def setField(c: Int, r: Int, v: String) {
  board(c * rows + row) = v
}
```

This is however only a good idea if you want to store your multi dimensional data in a single array (which can be interesting if you care about allocation structure and stuff like that). In this case I would recommend to write a generic method setField though.

If you instead want arrays of arrays fill already gives you that

```
val board = ArrayBuffer.fill(rows, cols)(".")
```

and then just update like this

```
board(x)(y) = "something"
```

You should however ask yourself whether you really need a mutable data structure and your program cannot be expressed more elegantly using immutable data structures. And also, if you really want a two dimensional vector if you want to represent something as a board of objects, especially if most of the board is "empty". It could be much more elegant to use a map:

```
val board = Map[(Int, Int), String]() // empty board
val nextBoard = bord + ((2,3) -> "something")
```

Comment: What is the advantage of `tabulate` over `fill`? Or maybe `fill` just will not work here?

Comment: tabulate returns a nested structure, i.e. in this case ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[String]] which is what you would typically have in Java as well.

Comment: By the way, there is also Array.tabulate(...) which would be preferable if you do not need arrays of variable size.

Comment: Yeah, I don't. I just overcomplicated everything. Thanks for help.

Comment: There is no advantage of using `tabulate` here, as you are not doing anything depending on the values of `x` and `y`. You should just use `fill`, as follows: `ArrayBuffer.fill(rows, cols)(".")`

Comment: RIght, I got confused by the question to implement setField